# how can i add condition in tab bar?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

i want to add condition in tabbar.

i want to do like this .if my id is not selected than that tab not open and it go to tab bar one. this id i select in tab bar one . so if this id selected then it open 2nd tab page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` delegate has the method `– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`. You use this and  the properties `selectedViewController` and `selectedIndex` to conditionally change the selected tab.

However, be careful. You should avoid making the interface behave in unexpected ways.

Comment: As Benedict said, if you are going to do this don't make it counter intuitive. When a user taps on a tab that you want to block temporarily, post a UIAlertView and tell them what to do to let them in. It's just good manners.